# Transfer ERC20 Token with vyper

Tags: tokens, vyper

Hello i m learning vyper and i have this issue: I deployed a standard ERC20 token contract using vyper default contract: https://github.com/ethereum/vyper/blob/master/examples/tokens/ERC20.vy

When i write my own contract to interact with it i have an issue transfering tokens from the current address that has tokens to the desired address, here is the code that i wrote in vyper to do the transfer:

```
contract Pcoin():
    def transfer(_to : address, _value : uint256) -> bool: modifying

@public
def transfer(_token_contract: address, _to: address, _value: uint256) -> bool:
    return Pcoin(_token_contract).transfer(_to, _value)
```

When i call the transfer method i get a failed transaction.
I tried also using the transferFrom method:

```
contract Pcoin():
    def transferFrom(_from : address, _to : address, _value : uint256) -> bool: modifying

@public
def transfer(_token_contract: address, _from: address, _to: address, _value: uint256) -> bool:
    return Pcoin(_token_contract).transferFrom(_from, _to, _value)
```

Also no luck with that.

Can someone please point out what i m doing wrong, Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure your contract holds a sufficient token balance? (Does it own at least `_value` tokens?) Or in the `transferFrom` case, are you sure your contract has a sufficient allowance set by the `_from` address?

Comment: @smarx Thanks for the reply, when i call the transfer method i m calling it from an address that has more than 900 tokens and i m sending 1 as _value.
In the transferFrom case i have previously called the approve method from the token contract directly to add the _spender address and a _value to the allowances map

Comment: Sorry, but which address has the tokens? There are three addresses involved: the `Pcoin` contract, the contract you've shared here (let's call that contract `Foo`), and the account that's invoking `Foo.transfer`. So you call `Foo.transfer`, and then it calls `Pcoin.transfer`. For that second call to work, `Foo` must have a sufficient balance of Pcoins.

Comment: @smarx The address that has the tokens is the address that is calling Foo.transfer, the contract Foo does not have any variable that is holding tokens, should it have it?

Comment: Well, you can use `transferFrom` in that case. Just make sure the `_from` address has called `Pcoin.approve(Foo, <amount>)` first.

Comment: @smarx So the approve must be called with the contract address, not with the address that is calling the Foo contract, correct?

Comment: Correct. `Foo` is the one doing the transferring, so it either needs to hold tokens itself (to call `transfer`) or it needs to be authorized to transfer from some other token holder (`transferFrom`).

Comment: @smarx Thank you very very much, towmorrow i ll have the time to try that, i ll let you know :)

Comment: @smarx I was able to try it and it worked like a charm :) thank you again